# Issue extracting a gz file on Linux

Tags: linux, compression, gunzip

I downloaded a file with a .gz extension only. It should be a folder with more files inside but when I do

```
$gunzip DOd.gz
```

What I get is a binary file DOd without extensions. If I check what the file is I get

```
$file DOd
DOd: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=dcbc85e17b9e60e67973f488eca1b930b4cd9d9d, not stripped
```

Any idea how to get the contents of this file?

Comment: This has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: @dlmeetei gzip is not an archiver. This is a single compressed file.

Comment: My bad, I thought tar.gz, retracting comment

Answer (score 0):

This don't seem to be a compressed file, by the file output it's a binary file, a executable, IF AND ONLY IF you REALLY trust the source of the file you can

```
chmod +x DOd
```

and try to run it

```
./DOd
```

it might be a self-extracting or something like that, but again, only if you really trust the source, if not try to download it again from another source.

Comment: I trust the source. I get ./DOd: error while loading shared libraries: libboost_system.so.1.55.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: @Atirag That means the executable needs a shared library that you don't have. But this is still not a programming question.

Comment: @melpomene I installed those libraries and still the same issue. Yes I know, I figured it was ok here since I saw similar questions when I searched on Google but I will delete it then.

Answer (score 0):

ELF is a linux executable format.